# Not able to get the code from oauth2/v2.0/authorize

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get the "code" using [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize). However I am redirecting to sign in to your account, how can I bypass the login ?

[image]

I have configurated API permissions for DevOps API as below,

[image]

Comment: To get `authorization_code`, user interaction is mandatory. You cannot bypass that login!

Comment: Tried to add query param grant_type=authorization_code. But still issue.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

When I ran authorization request in Postman, I got **same response** as you to sign in like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=<appID>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http://localhost
&response_mode=query
&scope= 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

To get authorization code, you need to run **same query** in browser that asks you to sign in like below:

[image]

After signing in successffully, you will get `code` value in **address bar** like this:

[image]

Now, use above `code` in below parameters to get access token via Postman like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope:499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default
code: <paste_code_from_above_screen>
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can use above access token to call **Azure DevOps API**.

Alternatively, you can directly generate token by selecting `O.Auth 2.0` and fill required fields like this from **Postman** itself which will automatically generate `code` internally:

[image]

If you give Callback URL as `https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback`, new window will be opened to sign in within Postman itself when you click on **Get New Access Token** button.

[image]

If **Authentication** is successful, you will get below screen:

[image]

After few seconds, it will be redirected to screen with **token** as below:

[image]

Now, you can call DevOps API queries by clicking `Use Token` like below:

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/sridevops14/_apis/Tokens/Pats?api-version=6.1-preview
```

**Response:**

[image]

Make sure to set `https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback` in redirect URIs of your application like below:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Sridevi - The idea is automate the login instead of browser intervention. Is there any way to bypass or use the basic authentication(username and passwrod ) to get the token and access the DevOps API ?

Comment: I got [this error](https://i.imgur.com/hc4yj0o.png) when I tried to list PATs with Basic Auth. As mentioned in this [Github issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/issues/571), you need to generate **Azure AD access token** with `Delegated` flow where user interaction is mandatory. Alternatively, you can use **username password flow(ROPC)** to generate bearer token if MFA is not enabled where user interaction is not required.